# Cerrar mi propia pregunta

Tags: soporte, votos-de-cierre

Los comentarios en [esta pregunta mía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21865/13065) me han aclarado que la discusión debe ser cerrada. No tengo ningún problema con eso, pero no la quiero eliminar porque

1. es un buen ejemplo de cómo tratar temas sexuales y
2. es un buen ejemplo de qué constituye una pregunta *too broad*.

¿Cómo puedo cerrar mi propia pregunta sin eliminarla ya que veo que es necesario y para que no mate el tiempo de otros?

Answer (score 3):

Aquí puedes encontrar la [lista completa de privilegios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) para el sitio y la reputación que necesitas para poder ejercerlos.

Necesitas 500 puntos para poder emitir [votos de cierre o de reapertura](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) sobre las preguntas de otros, pero en la parte de abajo de tu pregunta debería haber una serie de enlaces:

[image]

Con "close" deberías poder cerrar tu propia pregunta. Dependiendo de tu reputación es posible que solo veas

- Share: para compartir el enlace a un post
- Edit: para hacer/proponer (dependiendo de tu reputación) cambios en un post
- Flag: para marcar preguntas que necesiten atención especial.

Por debajo de los 500 puntos, vas a ver el enlace a "close" solo en tus propias preguntas, y cuando alcances el privilegios te aparecerá en todas.

De la misma manera, "delete" solo aparecerá en tus propios posts hasta que ganes reputación suficiente para manejar las [herramientas de moderación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) que te permitirán votar para borrar preguntas.

Comment: Y puede seleccionar "flag -> vote to close" si tiene < 500.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes borrar tu pregunta (y las respuestas, y los comentarios) con "Delete."

Comment: Eso es el opuesto de lo que pregunté…

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor - Perdón, parece que no entendí lo que tenías en mente.